# I am looking into how to create a SOAP client in ruby that is WS-I compatible. What should someone new to SOAP use?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon, ws-i

Both SOAP and WS-I compatibility are new to me. I have looked around and like the docs at [savonrb.com.](http://savonrb.com/version2.html) Is Savon WS-I compatible? Is there a better library that I should be using? Please, keep in mind good documentation is key since I will be doing this pretty much on my own.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does it mean to be "WS-I" compatible? The more important question for you will be which WS* you're going to work with.

There are many people who have used Savon to write SOAP clients. There might be other libs out there, but it always worked for me. You'll get good support for well formulated questions here at StackOverflow.

So go ahead and try.

I recommend to download SoapUI as well as it is a tremendous help in debugging a SOAP service.

Comment: I did look further into this a bit and it seems this, _"The more important question for you will b which WS* you're going to work with."_ is right on point. Cheers.